# Customizing Routes for view user profile -ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to programming. How can I create a custom URL for each user to retrieve data for the entered user? For instance, `www.hellothisis.com/sirushti`

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it's very difficult in the beginning.  However, have you read the [introduction to MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started)? There you will understand the basics and go further.

Even though you need to read that, the answer to you question is: [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=814)

You will see the default router and the "/sirushti" is the ID. In the controller you will likely to have something like this:

```
public JsonResult GetUser(string alias) { ... }
```

Take a look on the links I've sent you and you will get what it takes to use MVC!

Comment: Can u explain in details